# refer class method as attribute in Python but no error returned?

Tags: python, class

Here is my code, and I should refer class method printID as student.printID(), but I by mistake refer it by student.printID, I think it should return a name Error/Exception, but the code runs without any issues, any thoughts why?

```
class Student:
        def __init__(self, id):
                self.id = id
        def printID(self):
                print self.id

student = Student(100)

student.printID
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Why you *think it should return a name Error/Exception*?

Comment: It runs with the important "issue" that it doesn't do anything.

Comment: but will inform you that printID is a method in class Student

Comment: @Kasra, since there is no attribute called printID in class Student.

Comment: @AbhishekManandhar, do not quite catch your points? What do you mean inform? I tried to run but no output from console.

Comment: <bound method Student.printID of <__main__.Student instance at 0x02E2BD00>> This is the statement that you get if you execute just student.printID.

Comment: @LinMa: There is an attribute called `printID` on the class.  The value of that attribute is a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real distinction between methods and attributes in Python.  Methods *are* attributes.  `student.printID` is a reference to the method object.  When you add parentheses to it, you call that object.  In other words, `student.printID()` is no different than:

```
x = student.printID
x()
```

So it is not an error to type `student.printID` without parentheses.  It just gives you a reference to the method.  You might want to use that reference for some other purpose.  (In your particular case you didn't do anything with it, but Python doesn't know that.)

Comment: what do you mean no differences whether or not using parentheses? I tried when using parentheses, there does a difference which 100 is output -- when I using "student.printID()".

Comment: @LinMa: I'm not saying there's no difference between parentheses and no parentheses.  I'm saying there's no difference between methods and attributes (in terms of how you access them).  The parentheses don't mean "method", they mean "call".  A method is (roughly) just an attribute you can call.  The `.` is the "get attribute" part.  The `()` is the "call" part.  You got the attribute but didn't call it.